# urllib2 write to upstream

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to upload (large) random content to an HTTP endpoint. I create it, send it and it's never used again. So I'd like to skip saving it in a temporary file and using `{ 'file':open() }` as I also need to use form-urlencoded (instead of multipart).
I was using pycurl and its READFUNCTION option, but I don't want to depend on pycurl.

Is it possible to achieve this with *urllib2*?

I have this code:

```
def upload():
    url = 'http://localhost:9999/'
    values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : open(file).read() }
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
```

But as it stands, the whole file will be read when *values* is defined.
So if *file* was 1Gb of size, this wouldn't work very well (unless I misunderstood how it works). Also, I'd prefer not having to create the random-filled 1Gb file.

---

Ok, I can subclass *StringIO* as Daniel mentioned and create the random data in *read()*, but how do I make *urllib2* ask for *read()* chunks *while* uploading instead of having everything in memory at once?

---

In an attempt to be more specific, what I'd really like is something like `urlConnectionInstance.getOutputStream()` in Java that I can then write to. Or some way to tell *urllib2* to read from my own stream *while* it is actually dumping the data in the upload stream..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the httplib module in the python standard library:
http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.request

> ..Alternatively, it may be an open file object, in which case the contents of the file is sent; this file object should support fileno() and read() methods. ..

Comment: Together with StringIO, suggested by Daniel, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Even though I specified _urllib2_ in the question, the whole point was using standard library, not _urllib2_ specifically (my bad).. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly where you are having difficulty, but it sounds like you should be creating the image in a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) object, which is a string that acts like a file. You can then use the `read()` method to include this data as part of the standard urlencoded request data.

Comment: I have failed to explain indeed (or I fail to understand python read()). As I understand, if I type `values = { 'something' = open(file,'r').read() }` (or with a _StringIO_ object) I will load the whole data at the moment it instantiates _values_ dictionary. What I want is to be able to pass something to urllib2 that it will call upon _after_ connecting and write immediately to the stream _while_ I feed it with chunks of data, so it is not kept in memory. Like uploading 1Gb of random data...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that `urllib.urlencode` does not support your approach. If you create a class of your own that has a `read(size)` method that produces chunks of properly encoded data, that should work for the `data` parameter. Haven't tried this though.